# Numerical atomic orbitals vs Gaussian-type orbitals for molecular calculations

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-modeling, basis-sets, orbitals

Gaussian-type-orbitals (GTOs) are the work horse of modern molecular quantum chemistry calculations. They are computationally efficient and allow for analytic evaluation of integrals. However, there's an increasing number of *ab initio* packages that choose to use other alternatives for molecular calculations. One particular example being the numerical atomic orbitals (NAOs).

[For example, here's a similar discussion comparing GTOs and Slater-type-Orbitals (STOs)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4384/5884). That brings me to my question: What's the advantage of using a NAOs or other approaches that use numerically evaluated integrals?

Comment: See the open access review in https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qua.25968

Answer (score 2):

In some cases at least, NAO give smaller BSSE (basis set superposition error).

Here is the figure from [the FHI-aims paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010465509002033#fig004):

[image]

The BSSE here is the difference between red and black lines. It is small, and moreover, it converges to zero with basis set growth, that is really convenient.

The integration of NAO is more complicated that for GTO, but [there are some advanced numerical algorithms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGRnLrepkiw&t=630s). Probably advances in numerical integration contributed to the emergence of NAO codes.